# 3DTiles from GLTF with geodata

Tags: cesium, 3d-tiles

I have several gltf models (road signs). Each gltf represents the road sign type. I have geodata of where these signs should be located (Postgis or raw lat, lon, height) ~ 600000 point. I want to add this info on Cesium map. I can add entities one by one on cesium map with different modelMatrix for every entity.

So, as for me, i should generate 3d tiles from gltf model and geodata. But i cant find a way, how to do this.

As i understood, gltf hast its own positioning, which converts in Cesium with matrix.

For generating 3d tiles i should create many copies of the same gltf with different positioning? Or are there any instruments to create 3d tiles from one gltf and many coordinates, where it should be located?

Gltf example is on image. Data from location detemination:

```
coords_wgs84": "POINT Z (37.5881532832672 55.868931270484 174.464149389763)",
```

[image]

Comment: RESOLVED. This utility helps (i3dm)

https://github.com/Geodan/i3dm.export